# eclipse shows unchanged files on synchronise

Tags: eclipse, merge, commit

When i do a synchronisation of files or try to commit, there are also files shown that are not changed. 
This is only when i did a merge from an other workspace to the one i get those files in.

When i take a look at those files, they have no difference from the files on svn.

anyone any idea?

Comment: Which team provider are you using? SVN? CVS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that a newer version of Eclipse solves this problem!

when merging you get a 4 step wizard and in the latest step there is an option 'ignore ancestry'

if this is clicked, there wont be taken other files into this merge and the problem isn't there.

hip hip hooray

Comment: What version of Eclipse is that? I'm using the latest (Helios) and I see this issue with the SVN plugin (subclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the SVN **properties** on the files changed? SVN records the semantic information (merged revision range) in a property `svn:mergeinfo` when using the `svn merge` command.

It doesn't matter whether you use svn merge on the command line or Eclipse Team. Please read the documentation on [mergeinfo](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo) to see what is going on. The property will track your merge history in the repository (a significant improvement over e.g. CVS).

(Edited after comment)

Comment: it does not happen on all files, only 2 or 3 of the whole project.
I dont use the command to merge my different projects, i use the merge option in Eclipse for this. right click on a project-> team -> merge